# ffmpeg usage - quad core still overloaded

Tags: linux, encoding, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a 3.2GHz Quad Core Xeon E3-1230 CPU, Passmark CPU mark Score of 8,200, 32GB ram - and I can't do more than 4 ffmpeg commands/sessions without being overloaded. When I execute a ffmpeg session, it's telling me that it's not using muliple cores, only one. Why is that? How can I get ffmpeg to fully use all the cpu cores I have?

Thank you in advance for any kind of suggestions.

ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version N-42487-gfedefe4-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 13 2012 23:18:33 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
  libavutil      51. 64.100 / 51. 64.100
  libavcodec     54. 37.100 / 54. 37.100
  libavformat    54. 16.104 / 54. 16.104
  libavdevice    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavfilter     3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Comment: I think the `-threads` option allows you to specify how many threads to use and this can make it use multiple CPUs.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I am using it incorrectly, but I have tried ffmpeg -threads 4 and it's still telling using single core.

Comment: Generally even one FFmpeg process will automatically use all the CPU cores it can get its hands on.  What version of FFmpeg are you using?

Comment: @blahdiblah ffmpeg version N-42487-gfedefe4-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: @thevoipman Just out of curiosity, how are you measuring CPU core usage?

Comment: @blahdiblah i just do top and i see 90+ all around